# Sites which provide annotated openings (preferably interactive)

Tags: opening, online, annotation

I'm looking for a site that provides **well-annotated openings**, giving at least the first 15-20 moves of major openings and allowing me to explore their main variations and lines (by clicking on the relevant moves on an online chessboard).

For example, if I am learning Queen's Gambit Declined, I'd expect it to display something along the lines of this (more detailed and expertly annotated, of course, and with a diagram)

> **1. d4** A popular  opening move, which gives White a solid position. **1. ... d5** Black's reply is quite common, and preserves the symmetry of the situation. **2. c4** This is the Queen's gambit - if accepted, it can provide White great momentum and development. **2. ...e6** Black turns down the gambit  and prefers to keep the position interesting. *2. ...dxc4* is not really got for Black as White can get the pawn back soon by [sequence of moves] followed by a bishop move.

And if I play **2. ...c6**, I'd expect something like this (but again more detailed and with a diagram to help.)

> **2. ...c6** This changes the opening to the Slav defense.

### My question

Is there any site online that provides **detailed, annotated openings at least 15-20 moves deep** and allows me to explore **variations and lines (also
annotated)**?

### Note

The site needn't focus on other parts of the game. I'm focusing on the opening for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikibook Chess Opening Theory](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chess_Opening_Theory) has similar aims but I don't think it quite meets all of your requirements. Still, it's the website closest to meeting them that I can think of, so I hope it helps. Being a wiki, it's still evolving and of course one can always wonder about the expertise of the authors.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into it. What do you think about ChessGames.com?

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed the closest to what I need. Plus, I found Chess Position Trainer, which helps too. I've accepted and upvoted your answer!

Comment: @HarryWeasley, thanks and sorry I missed your other question. I use chessgames.com to look up historical games but I'm not a member. As far as I can tell, their opening tool lets you see the statistics but has no annotations, unless there's something else in the members-only area that I haven't seen.

Comment: I looked it up, and I think they provide some kind of in-depth opening analysis (called 'Opening Laboratory' or 'Position Laboratory' or something) for premium members, but not for non-premium members. Thanks again, the Wikibook helps rather well!